# Should I mount using beforeEach() and set props for each test or mount a specific component at the start of each test? (using Enzyme, Chai and Mocha)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme, chai

I've recently starting programming.  I'm on a team who is programming in React and is using Enzyme, Mocha and Chai for unit testing.  See package versions below.

When testing a component where there are several use cases that require different prop values, should I use beforeEach() and then setProps() in each test, or should I do an explicit mount() (or shallow()) at the start of each test?  Does it matter?

For example, I could use beforeEach() to mount without any props and then use setProps() in each test like this (using pseudocode):

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {

   beforeEach(... let component = mount(<MyComponent />) ...)

   it('tests use case 1', () => {
      // set prop A = 123
      component.setProps({A: 123})
      // assert some stuff
   })

   it('tests use case 2, () => {
      // set prop A = 456 and B = 'foo'
      component.setProps({A: 456})
      component.setProps({B: 'foo'})
      // assert some stuff
   })

})
```

or I could do a use-case specific mount at the start of each test, passing in props in the mount, like this:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {

   it('tests use case 1', () => {
      ...mount(<MyComponent A=123 />)
      // assert some stuff
   })

   it('tests use case 2, () => {
      ...mount(<MyComponent A=456 B='foo' />)
      // assert some stuff
   })

})
```

What are the pros and cons of each method?  Is there a best practice?

**Packages**

- "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
- "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
- "mocha": "^5.0.0",
- "chai": "3.5.0"

Comment: I don't think you can set the props after mounting like in your first scenario, so if the props are different per test, the second variant is the way to go

Comment: @PatrickHund In beforeEach, the mount() result is assigned to a variable.  E.g., let component = mount(...).  Then in each test case, you can do component.setProps({A: 123}).  This seems to work (i.e., the assertions pass), but have we misunderstood something?

Comment: You're right, I wasn't aware you could do this with Enzyme. I learned something, thx :-)

Comment: @MarnieA. When you do `setProps` it will execute the update life cycle of the component, it's not same as passing the props initially. So when you want to test the componentDidMount/useEffect with some dependency, you won't be able to do with setProps. 
I personally prefer the 2nd approach with a factory method as it's cleaner and everything that the other reader needs to understand is at one place. 

Here is a nice article by Kent.C.Dodds on such patterns. https://kentcdodds.com/blog/test-isolation-with-react/

Comment: Here is an example for such pattern. https://gist.github.com/joshdover/235714771d94509a83609b16d232014a

Answer (score 0):

For class components there is `componentDidMount` and `constructor` while for functional components there is `useEffect(..., [])`. All that things are called just once.

On the other side for approach #2 it's still needed to test props update in separate test case to ensure component handles that properly. Otherwise you may miss the case when say using the same component in different `<Route>` does not fetch data on navigation(that happen in `componentDidMount` only)

Say if you have

```
<Route path="/Album/:id/author" component={UserScreen} />
<Route path="/user/:id/" component={UserScreen} />
```

and if you can navigate directly from first to second it means React-Router will not re-create `UserScreen` but just update instance already rendered. So with approach #1 you would cover this case with tests automatically. While approach #2 will need you testing `componentDidUpdate` behavior explicitly.

I'm not sure what's better but want to highlight that difference may happen between testing flow and real-project-flow.

Comment: Thanks, @skyboyer.  My tests are for class components.  I'm a little unclear what you mean in your second paragraph.  Can you paraphrase in hopes that it clarifies it for me?  I'm pretty new to all of this.  Thanks!

Comment: added example and enlarge description.